# Paypal IPN how can i get my order ID?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm developing a transaction on order with custom code, and i need to send my order id to payola and get it back with IPN call so i can reload my order price, and update status

i can't figure out witch variable to use

Answer (score 1):

Here you'll find an overview of the PayPal variables (depending on which API you use):
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

If you don't find a proper variable you can add a GET parameter to the `notify_url` (which is the URL for IPN). If you do so I would suggest to hash the value at least (better encrypt). If the IPN comes in you just have to read the GET-Value ( and decrypt it) and you have the reference to your data.

Hope it helps,
Sascha